# How to implement Regex filter in a React search bar?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, regex-group

I've been trying to implement a Regex filter in my React project - it's a search bar which I've got to filter even mixed letters in a word.

eg. If I have "Stark" as word or "Karstark", once I type "stk" the word "Stark" should appear.

I already can search if I type "ark" for "Stark" or "ol" for "Bolton"

**This is the Json file**

```
[
    {
          "id" : 1,
          "title": "Stark",
          "date": "17-08-2017"
    },
    {    
          "id" : 2,
          "title": "Lannister",
          "date": "17-08-2017"
    },
    {
          "id" : 3,
          "title": "Targaryen",
          "date": "16-08-2017"
    },
    {
          "id" : 4,
          "title": "Karstark",
          "date": "16-08-2017"
    },
    {
          "id" : 5,
          "title": "Bolton",
          "date": "15-08-2017"
    },
    {
          "id" : 6,
          "title": "Martell",
          "date": "15-08-2017"
    }

]
```

**This is the search file**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const data = require('../../data.json');


function searchingFor(term){
    return function(x){
            return x.title.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) || !term ;

    }
}



class Results extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

            this.state = {
                    data: data ,
                    term : '',
            }
            this.searchHandler = this.searchHandler.bind(this);
    }

    searchHandler(event){
        this.setState({ term: event.target.value})
    }

  render () {
        const {term, data} = this.state;
        return (
        <section>
                    <div className="input-group input-group-lg" >
                        <input type="text" 
                        className="form-control" 
                        aria-label="Large" 
                        placeholder="Pesquise uma nota" 
                        aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" 
                        onChange={this.searchHandler}
                        value={term}
                         />
                    </div>
                    <div className="App-maintitle">
                        <h1>Notas</h1>
                    </div>
        {
          data.filter(searchingFor(term)).map((element, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="App-row" key={index} >
              <div className="App-titledata">
                {element.title}
              </div>
              <div className="App-date">
                {element.date}
              </div>
            </div>
            )
          })
        }
        </section>     
    )
  }
}

export default Results;
```

Comment: This may help: [`\bs*t*a*r*k*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/TV8CCd/3)

Comment: @Sergio May you please show me how to implement the Regex inside the code. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're talking about fuzzy/approximate matching, which is a bit more high-level than Regexp search. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rough overview of how you would implement a search. Basically we're checking to see whether the `item.title` includes `term` and if it does, filter out everything else and map the data.

```
    {
      data.filter(item => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()).map((element, index) => {
      return (
        <div className="App-row" key={index} >
          <div className="App-titledata">
            {element.title}
          </div>
          <div className="App-date">
            {element.date}
          </div>
        </div>
        )
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your filtered data:

```
data.filter(item => {
  return term.split("").every(internalItem => {
    return item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(internalItem.toLowerCase()) !== -1
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for it. However can you support me where i supposed to place this code?

Comment: Anyone can please support me with this. I am still stuck on that. Thanks!